# Javascript replace() doesn't work in VS - unknown character

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, replace, special-characters

I'm trying to use the javascript replace function to replace curly quote with straight quotes:

```
var EditedContent = content.replace(/“/g, '"');
```

This works great in a little proof of concept html file I've whipped up, but when it's in a visual studio project, it replaces the curly quote with a symbol that suggests 'unknown character':

[image: Unknown character]

How can I resolve this issue so that I can use the application properly when debugging?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use unicode:

```
... = content.replace(/\u201C/g, '"');
```

You can find unicode equivalents of various quotes [here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html).